# Angular error formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive. You'll want to add a formGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using angular reactive. I am binding stepper from JSON .

`ERROR Error: formArrayName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).`

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.bondTypesFeilds = bondTypes;

    for (let bondType of this.bondTypesFeilds.form_fields) {
      var fgroup = this._formBuilder.group({});

      for (let k = 0; k < bondType.step[1].fields.length; k++) {
        fgroup.addControl(bondType.step[1].fields[k].id,
          new FormControl('', Validators.required));
      }

    }

    this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
        fgroup
      ])
    })
  }
```

```
<mat-step *ngFor="let bonds of bondTypesFeilds.form_fields;let p =index" formGroupName="0" [stepControl]="formArray?.get([0])">
  <form [formGroup]="formGroupA" *ngIf="renderLicenseForm()" >
    <ng-template matStepLabel>
      <p class="stepper-label" id="{{p}}">{{bonds.step[0].title}}</p>
    </ng-template>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      <div class="col-md-8 text-right card">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let fields of bonds.step[1].fields">
          <div class="full-width">
            <div *ngIf="fields.type == 'dropdownlist'">
              <span class="labelpad">{{fields.question}}</span>
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-select class="select-data" id={{fields.id}} formControlName={{fields.id}}
                            placeholder={{fields.placeholder_text}}>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let s of statelist" value={{s.id}}>
                    {{s.text}} </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="fields.type == 'textarea'">
              <span class="labelpad">{{fields.question}}</span>
              <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <textarea matInput cdkTextareaAutosize #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize"
                   cdkAutosizeMinRows="1" cdkAutosizeMaxRows="5"
                   placeholder={{fields.placeholder_text}}
                   formControlName={{fields.id}}></textarea>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</mat-step>
```

Comment: Your will have `formArrayName` somewhere in your HTML. But your post does not have it. The error is happening elsewhere that is not in your post.

Comment: <mat-horizontal-stepper labelPosition="bottom" formArrayName="formArray" (selectionChange)="selectionChange($event)" [linear]="true"
            #stepper>